# Broken background in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, background

I have a gwt project that has a panel where I added a style name to called "dock". When I open my application in Firefox everything is fine but in Chrome, Safari and IE the background isn't complete. This is my css code:

```
.dock {
background: #e3e8f3 url(img/hborder.png) repeat-x 0px -1000px;
padding: 4px 4px 4px 8px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
position: relative; 
}
```

This is how it looks in Firefox (it should look like this) [Screenshot](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/7774/firefoxscreenshot.jpg)

And this is how it looks in the other browsers like chrome: [Screenshot](http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/8742/chromescreenshot.jpg)

Any ideas how to correct this?
Thanks in advance.

[EDIT:]

This is the html code generated by gwt:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="dock" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                <button type="button" class="gwt-Button gwt-Button-helpButton" title="Zoek hulp"></button>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                <button type="button" class="gwt-Button gwt-Button-browseButton" title="Blader door de database."></button>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                <button type="button" class="gwt-Button gwt-Button-statButton" title="Laat populaire boeken zien"></button>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                <button type="button" class="gwt-Button gwt-Button-search" title="Zoek een boek"></button>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                <input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox gwt-TextBox-searchQuery">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I noticed with firebug the panel also has got this css markup (this markup is automatically added when compiling in gwt).

```
element.style {
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Vinay B R done see the edit in first post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding a fixed height to your .dock, which is same as background image height, i.e.

```
.dock { height: 100px }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the url in quotes:

```
background: #e3e8f3 url("img/hborder.png") repeat-x 0px -1000px;
```

Last time I checked that was the correct format.

Edit: Ah, your problem seems to be that tables aren't responding for some strange reason. Try this.

```
background: url("img/hborder.png") repeat-x 0px -1000px;
background-color: #e3e8f3;
```

Comment: Tried it but it didn't change anything. Thanks anyway for your answer.